# AngularJS echo very fast changes

Tags: angularjs, websocket, angularjs-scope

Hi i am using angular websocke
when i switch on websocket and open the connection or close a connection the $rootScope model was not change.
Service code :

```
.factory("MyData", function($websocket, $rootScope) {
        return {
            open: function () {
                $rootScope.connection_status = 'connecting';
                window.dataStream =  $websocket(Config.socketUrl);

                dataStream.onError(function () {
                      console.log('error')
                })
                dataStream.onOpen(function () {
                    $rootScope.connection_status = 'online';
                    console.log('now online',$rootScope.connection_status)
                })

                dataStream.onClose(function () {
                    $rootScope.connection_status = 'offline';
                    console.log('now offline',$rootScope.connection_status)
                })
            },
            close: function () {
                dataStream.close()
            }
        };
    })
```

The Controller :

```
.controller('SocketController', function ($scope, MyData) {

        $scope.MyData  = MyData
        $scope.MyData.open()

    })
```

The view :

```
{{ connection_status }}
<div ng-switch="connection_status">

    <a ng-switch-when="offline" ng-click="MyData.open()">Connect</a>
    <a ng-switch-when="online" ng-click="MyData.close()">Disconnect</a>
    <a ng-switch-when="connecting" ng-click="MyData.close()">cancel</a>
</div>
```

In this code {{ connection_status }} dont works correctly that means , we have two possible cases

1. {{ connection_status }} is online (correct) and $rootScope.connection_status is online
2. {{ connection_status }} is connecting (incorrect) but $rootScope.connection_status is online why?